# How to get CDATA texts from XML by id in tags

Tags: php, xml, cdata

I know how to access tags in XML using PHP but this time, I have to use a function `getText($textId)` to access text content in those tags but I tried so many things that I am desperate for help.

I tried this

```
$doc->load("localisations_EN.xml");
$texts = $doc->getElementsByTagName("txt");
$elem = $doc->getElementById("home");
$children = $elem->childNodes;

 foreach ($children as $child) {

     if ($child->nodeType == XML_CDATA_SECTION_NODE) {
           echo $child->textContent . "<br/>";
        }
} 


 print_r($texts);
 print_r($doc->getElementById('home'));


 foreach ($texts as $text) 
 {
     foreach($text->childNodes as $child) {
         if ($child->nodeType == XML_CDATA_SECTION_NODE) {
             echo $child->textContent . "<br/>";
         }

     }
 }
```

Then I tried this but I don't know how to access the string value

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("localisations_EN.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
print_r($xml);
$description = $xml->xpath("//txt[@id='home']");
var_dump($description);
```

And I got something like this

> array(1) { [0]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (1) { ["@attributes"]=>
>   array(1) { ["id"]=> string(4) "home" } } }

This is the XML file I have to use

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<localisation application="test1">
    <part ID="menu">
        <txt id="home"><![CDATA[Home]]></txt>
        <txt id="news"><![CDATA[News]]></txt>
        <txt id="settings"><![CDATA[Settings]]></txt>
    </part>
    <part ID="login">
        <txt id="id"><![CDATA[Login]]></txt>
        <txt id="password"><![CDATA[Password]]></txt>
        <txt id="forgetPassword"><![CDATA[Forget password?]]></txt>
    </part>
</localisation>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

simplexml element has a `__toString()` magic function that will return the text content of the element (however, not the text content of sub-elements)
so your simplexml code should be

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("localisations_EN.xml");
$description = (string) $xml->xpath("//txt[@id='home']")[0];
            //   ^-- triggers __toString()               ^-- xpath returns array
```

because xpath returns an array of elements, you need to fetch one (or more) and cast it to string. To get the immediate contents of that element.

### with DOMDocument:

don't know why you go for the (non-existant) child nodes there. CDATA is just syntax to say "don't parse this, this is data"

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->load("localisations_EN.xml");
$texts = $doc->getElementsByTagName('txt');
foreach($texts as $text) {
    if($text->getAttribute('id') == 'home') { 
         // prepend hasAttribute('id') if needed to if clause above
         $description = $text->textContent;
    }
}
```

also, `$doc->getElementById()` probably only works, if the DTD has set some attribute as ID. Since your xml doesn't do that (it doesn't name a DTD) it doesn't work.

### with DOMDocument and DOMXPath

```
// $doc as before
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$description = $xpath->evaluate('//txt[@id="home"]')[0]->textContent;
// as before, xpath returns an array, that's why  ---^
```